# CSS3 Transitions like Twitter header

Tags: html, css, user-interface, frontend

You know how Twitter's menu does a slide in from the BOTTOM of their `bottom-border`? I'm trying to do the same with transitions on `css3` and my `border-bottom` slides in from the top to bottom AT the bottom when I want it go slide from the bottom to the top AT the bottom like Twitter's menu.

Here's my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8emkgzyb/

```
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
ul li {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px;
    display:inline;
}
ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 4px;
    display:inline;
    color: #000; 
    transition: all .3s;
    line-height: 20px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    border-bottom-width: 0px;
}
 ul li a:hover {
    transition: all .3s;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: red;
    border-bottom-width: 4px;
}
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and HTML

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Locations</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

something like that? 
I don't know if I understood it correct.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/SzymonDziewonski/agwafk84/)

```
ul li a {
    height: 24px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding: 4px;
    color: #000; 
    transition: all .3s;
    line-height: 20px;
    border: 0px solid red;
    display: block;
}
 ul li a:hover {
    transition: all .3s;
    height: 20px;
    border-bottom: 4px solid red;
}
```

Comment: no probklem, just a 1-2 min work. Glad I could help :).